# Add data into 2 entities with 1 form symfony 3

Tags: symfony, entity, roles, user-roles

I have register form. 
When I save the user, i want to add row in other database table. The second table is for role and it has only 2 fields: user_id and role_id. 
This is my structure of database:

```
 CREATE TABLE `roles` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_B63E2EC75E237E06` (`name`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=3
    ;

    CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `fullName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_1483A5E9586CA949` (`userName`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `UNIQ_1483A5E9E7927C74` (`email`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;

    CREATE TABLE `user_roles` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `role_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `role_id`),
    INDEX `IDX_54FCD59FA76ED395` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `IDX_54FCD59FD60322AC` (`role_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_54FCD59FA76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_54FCD59FD60322AC` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

So, here is my UserController, where I am saving the user:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\UserType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="user_register")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user,$user->getPlainPassword());
            $user->setPassword($password);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute("cat_index");
        }
        return $this->render('users/register.html.twig',
            array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

I want every user to have role with id=1. So every registered user will have ROLE_USER. 
In my Entity User i have not a setter for role. i have only getter. How to add and setter which is checking for role with id 1 and set the role for the user?
Here is my User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\AppBundle;
use AppBundle\Controller\SecurityController;
use AppBundle\Repository\RoleRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use AppBundle\Entity\Role;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Repository;


/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="userName", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $userName;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $plainPassword;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fullName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fullName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_roles",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     * @var Collection|Role[]
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set userName
     *
     * @param string $userName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUserName($userName)
    {
        $this->userName = $userName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserName()
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set fullName
     *
     * @param string $fullName
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFullName($fullName)
    {
        $this->fullName = $fullName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fullName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->fullName;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = [];
        foreach ($this->roles as $role){
            $roles[] = $role->getName();
        }
        if(empty($roles)){
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        }
        return $roles;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->getId(),
            $this->getUserName(),
            $this->getPassword()
        ]);
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list(
            $this->id,
            $this->userName,
            $this->password
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPlainPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->plainPassword.'';
    }

    /**
     * @param string $plainPassword
     */
    public function setPlainPassword(string $plainPassword)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
    }
}
```

I am using symfony 3
How to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On your UserType you can set your `roles` field to use `EntityType` [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/forms/types/entity.html). That will automatically save the roles entity on flush.

Comment: Not really what is being asked though the question does meander a bit.  Read the docs might be a more useful answer.